# Avoid MapBasic crash when unable to open file

Tags: mapinfo, error, mapbasic, tab

I'm working on some MapBasic code and in the process I want it to open the .tab files in a given folder. But when it reaches a .tab file that it is not able to open (e.g. attached to a raster that does not exist, ID/DAT/MAP files missing, etc.), I get the following warning message and it won't open the files that come after it:

[image]

Snppet of code:

```
If FileNames(i) like "%TAB" then
    Open Table FileNames(i)
End If
```

Is there away to have the code continue after this type of error is encountered so that it will load all of the non-corrupted files? Or better yet have the code load all the files and give a list/report at the end of which files it was unable to open?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MapBasic provides some error handling functions. In this case you would use the OnError statement to enable an error handling routine which could, for example, log the error in a text file or just resume at the next line of code. Have a read in the MapBasic reference guide (in the documentation folder of your MapInfo installation) of the OnError and Resume statements particularly.

e.g.

```vb
Declare Sub Main

Sub Main()

    '.... do some stuff

    OnError GoTo CaughtEx  '// turn on error handling
    If FileNames(i) like "%TAB" then
        Open Table FileNames(i)
    End If
    OnError GoTo 0 '// turn off error handling

Exit Sub

CaughtEx:  '// error handling routine
    '// Log error here...
    Print "Failed to open table " & FileNames(i)
    Resume Next  '// resume code at line after the one which threw the error
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to accomplish this. One way is to create a function for opening tables where you would process whole operation. This is just a fast example:

```
Function OpenTab(ByVal TableName as String, ByVal sAlias as String) As Logical

    OnError Goto NotOpen  

    Open Table TableName+".TAB" As sAlias Interactive
    Print "Requested table:" + sAlias
    OpenTab = TRUE
    Exit Function

    NotOpen:
    OpenTab = FALSE
    print "---------------------------------------"
    print "Failed to open table "+TableName
    print "---------------------------------------"

End Function
```